# collapse не правильно работает

Tags: html, bootstrap

Помогите, как сделать правильно, чтобы collapse открывался внутри нажатой таблицы?
Сейчас он открывается в самом низу таблицы.

Мой код:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
   <tbody data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="card card-body">
    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
  </div>
</div>
```

Нашел пример как надо:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Только как например:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  
  <div class="container">
    <table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">#</th>
          <th scope="col">First</th>
          <th scope="col">Last</th>
          <th scope="col">Handle</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody >
        <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample-1">
          <th scope="row">1</th>
          <td>Mark</td>
          <td>Otto</td>
          <td>@mdo</td>  
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4" class="p-0">
            <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample-1">
              <div class="card card-body">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample-2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample-2">
          <th scope="row">2</th>
          <td>Mark</td>
          <td>Otto</td>
          <td>@mdo</td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4" class="p-0">
            <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample-2">
              <div class="card card-body">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    
  </div>
```